# Get last known location always return NULL SDK 23

Tags: android, google-location-services

I want to get the user Location but the method always return null this is my Code :

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    SystemProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(),true);
     UserLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(SystemProvider);
           if(UserLocation==null)
           {
               Log.i("Exc2","No Location");
               mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0,0)).title("No Location"));
               mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(0,0),10));
           }
           else {
               double one = UserLocation.getLatitude();
               double two = UserLocation.getLongitude();
               mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(one, two)).title("HMS"));
               mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(one, two), 10));
           }
```

i have tried many ways but nothing happened even when I opened Google maps on the emulator and pressed on the gps button it was unable to get my current location
thanks in advance

Comment: have a look answer for step by step guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38397092/5955362

Answer (score 0):

check permission in Manifest file
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

try passing service location manually

Location UserLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps");

if your andorid is 6.0 you must check for permission before use location beacause they can be revoked

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **Fused Location API** for receiving **location updates** where it is recommended from Google.
Check this url: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html it will help you.